# Print into one file the query result of a database file

Tags: bash, join, grep

I have two files:

```
abc
ghi
```

and the second (aka database file)

```
abc   123
def   456
ghi   789
```

and I want to query the database file to print the second column into the second column of the first file if there is a match
So my output would be

```
abc   123
ghi   789
```

logically, I understand what I have to do, but I lack the commands in bash for it...

my attempt was to use `join` with the `-1` but I do not understand how to implement it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`join` is a little overkill here (as it requires sorting) because file1 has just one column.  Can you not use `grep -f`?

```
grep -Fwf file1 file2
```

- `-F` treats the content of file1 as strings, not patterns
- `-w` looks for the whole word to match

Answer (score 1):

what's wrong with `join`?

```
$ cat 1
abc
ghi
$ cat 2
abc 123
def 456
ghi 789
$ join 1 2
abc 123
ghi 789
```

then if you want to store it somewhere just redirect the stdout.